# Python: Why the parameter passed in the class initializing function is changed while I am only changing local class variable

Tags: python

I am creating a Node class to generate a Tree structure in Python. which will then be used in a tree-recovery algorithm.

However, I found it strange that when I set some default value to my class initialization function, it does NOT work. But if I force it to list out all parameters when called (ie. no default value), it magically works.

Because I am not that familiar with the underlying mechanism in Python 3.6, so could anyone please let me know what is going on inside?

Some information of my python: conda environment py3.6 on win10

Here is the code:

Without default value: (correct result)

```
class Node:
    names = set()
    parent = None
    children = []

    def __init__(self, my_names, my_parent, my_children):

        self.names = set(my_names)
        self.parent = my_parent
        self.children = my_children

        print(my_names, my_parent, my_children)

        if not (my_parent is None):
            print(my_parent, my_parent.children)
            (my_parent.children).append(self)

        print(my_names, my_parent, my_children)


        for c in my_children:
            c.parent = self

    def print_info(self):
        print('name:     ', self.names)
        if not (self.parent is None):
            print('parent:   ', self.parent.names)
        else:
            print('parent:   ')

        print('children: ', end='')
        for c in self.children:
            print(c.names, end=' ')
        print()

a = Node(["a"], None, [])
a.print_info()
print(a)
print("==================================")
b = Node(["b"], a, [])
print("==================================")
c = Node(["c"], a, [])
print("==================================")
a.print_info()
print("==================================")
b.print_info()
print("==================================")
c.print_info()
```

The (correct) result is:

```
    ['a'] None []
['a'] None []
name:      {'a'}
parent:   
children: 
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8>
==================================
['b'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> []
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> []
['b'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> []
==================================
['c'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> []
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34E0>]
['c'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F34A8> []
==================================
name:      {'a'}
parent:   
children: {'b'} {'c'} 
==================================
name:      {'b'}
parent:    {'a'}
children: 
==================================
name:      {'c'}
parent:    {'a'}
children:
```

With default value (wrong result):

```
    class Node:
    names = set()
    parent = None
    children = []

    ### => only changes:
    def __init__(self, my_names, my_parent=None, my_children=[]):

        self.names = set(my_names)
        self.parent = my_parent
        self.children = my_children

        print(my_names, my_parent, my_children)

        ### => this line changes the content of "my_children"
        if not (my_parent is None):
            print(my_parent, my_parent.children)
            (my_parent.children).append(self)

        print(my_names, my_parent, my_children)


        for c in my_children:
            c.parent = self

    def print_info(self):
        print('name:     ', self.names)
        if not (self.parent is None):
            print('parent:   ', self.parent.names)
        else:
            print('parent:   ')

        print('children: ', end='')
        for c in self.children:
            print(c.names, end=' ')
        print()

a = Node(["a"])
a.print_info()
print(a)
print("==================================")
b = Node(["b"], a) # call without all parameters
print("==================================")
c = Node(["c"], a) # call without all parameters
print("==================================")
a.print_info()
print("==================================")
b.print_info()
print("==================================")
c.print_info()
```

Wrong output:

```
    ['a'] None []
['a'] None []
name:      {'a'}
parent:   
children: 
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0>
==================================
['b'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> []
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> []
['b'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F3C18>]
==================================
['c'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F3C18>]
<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F3C18>]
['c'] <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09FAEF0> [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F3C18>, <__main__.Node object at 0x0000014EC09F3438>]
==================================
name:      {'a'}
parent:   
children: {'b'} {'c'} 
==================================
name:      {'b'}
parent:    {'c'}
children: {'b'} {'c'} 
==================================
name:      {'c'}
parent:    {'c'}
children: {'b'} {'c'}
```

As we can see the parent of b,c nodes (the children of Node a) seems to be a shared value. But actually I have no idea why this happens as I did not refer to the class variable at all...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Default list values in Python is changable inside function and persisted between function calls.

Comment: @CrazyElf I understand that. But I actually did not write to the ‘my_children’ inside my function and it still changes...That’s why I am confused.

Comment: No, actually you write. I explain it in aswer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `self.children = my_children` to `self.children = my_children.copy()` and code will work correct. When you change self.children inside function body, you change my_children also because self.children assigned by link to my_chidlren, not by value of it. Adding a '.copy()' make it assigned by value.
You can add some output to the end of `__init__` body to see for yourself what my_children is changed by `b = Node(["b"], a)` call:

```
print("children: ", self.children) 
print("my_children: ", my_children)

children:  [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000000008D82978>]
my_children:  [<__main__.Node object at 0x0000000008D82978>]
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Python implementation here is so tricky...I did not use list.copy() because I want the node to be able to 'see' their neighbour in the tree, but forgot that the objects in the list are also 'reference'. Thanks!